# Validation for Irish Eircode

Tags: javascript, regex, street-address

I'm wondering if there's a best practice for validation for the Irish Eircode format. My best attempt so far, using REGEX in JavaScript, is the following based on the official spec found on page 11 **[here](https://www.eircode.ie/docs/default-source/Common/prepareyourbusinessforeircode-edition3published.pdf?sfvrsn=2)**.

*(Page 11 based on the page numbers in the document, or page 12 if you include the cover)*

```
/^[A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9,W]{1}[\ \-]?[0-9,A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y]{4}$/
```

I didn't find any Eircode related questions on here so I thought I'd open up this one and see what other people thought, and to see what better/shorter/more efficient patterns anyone could come up with.

Edit: Removed commas as per @Asunez answer.

```
/^[ACDEFHKNPRTVWXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9W]{1}[\ \-]?[0-9ACDEFHKNPRTVWXY]{4}$/
```

Comment: Can you provide example of `Irish Eircode`??

Comment: https://www.eircode.ie/docs/default-source/Common/prepareyourbusinessforeircode-edition3published.pdf?sfvrsn=2

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since @Manwal's answer doesn't exactly do what it should, here is my attempt at shortening the regex for OP:

`(?:^[AC-FHKNPRTV-Y][0-9]{2}|D6W)[ -]?[0-9AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]{4}$`

Updated version supporting the A65 B2CD postcodes - `(?:^[AC-FHKNPRTV-Y][0-9]{2}|D6W)[ -]?[0-9AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]{4}$`

This is basically what your Regex is, with a few changes:

- Removed commas. You do not need commas to list items inside `[]` brackets.
- Added ranges where possible and where it would save some space (`C-F`, `V-Y`). Elsewhere it's not beneficial to add ranges, as it won't make regex shorter.
- You do not need to escape a space. " " in regex is literal.
- You also do not need to escape the dash if it's the last character in character class (square brackets)
- The first part of the regex is now in a non-capturing group to allow *OR*ing it with the only possible letter for 3rd position, the "D6W" case.

It is also possible to deal with `D6W` exclusively with lookbehind, but this is more of an art than regex.

See Regex Demo: [here](https://regex101.com/r/dU6eQ7/17)

You can also invert the character class to **not** include given characters, and while it doesn't make the regex shorter, it's also worth noting. However, you need to make sure that other characters (like dots, commas) are not included too. I do it by adding the `\W` token.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dU6eQ7/5)

Comment: You can shorten it even further by `^[AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]\d[0-9W][ -]?[0-9AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]{4}$`

Comment: @AlexeyShein Not necessarily - there is a difference between `\d` and `[0-9]`, the first one also accepts hebrew or other languages digits, while the second accepts only 0-9 exclusively.

Comment: @Asunez I think this difference can almost always be neglected, but, of course, you should know your dataset.

Comment: @ConorLuddy I edited my answer with an example of using negative character set - you may want to take a look at this.

Comment: Interesting technique @Asunez, I never thought of that - thanks!

Comment: Your regex has two issues: it allows dash (not defined in the eircode spec) and accepts all routing codes that end with W and are invalid like: A1W, C2W. 
Big plus for optional space - not defined but shown in eircode examples and following the same patter as British post-codes.

Comment: @iaforek That's true - as I mentiond in my answer, _It is also possible to deal with D6W exclusively with lookbehind_. However, as of my knowledge, it would make the regex way longer and less legible. My answer is the best I could think of without using lookarounds.

Answer (score 13):

According to Product guide chapter 1.5.4, allowed signs are:

| Component | Position | Allowed characters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Routing Keys | 1 | A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y |
| Routing Keys | 2 | 0-9 |
| Routing Keys | 3 | 0-9 with the exception of W for D6W |
| Unique Identifier | 4 | 0-9, A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y |
| Unique Identifier | 5 | 0-9, A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y |
| Unique Identifier | 6 | 0-9, A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y |
| Unique Identifier | 7 | 0-9, A,C,D,E,F,H,K,N,P,R,T,V,W,X,Y |

Every routing key must contain letter and two digits except ONE specific situation which is `D6W` code.

So codes beginning with `A5W`, `C6W`, `V0W` are invalid.

According to chapter 1.5.1 “Recommendations for Storage and Presentation”,

- An Eircode should always be stored as a single string of seven upper case characters in IT systems, i.e. A65F4E2.
- An Eircode should always be presented in upper case as two parts separated by a space, on stationary, mail items, computer forms, etc. i.e. A65 F4E2 and never A65F4E2.

Codes stored in the database shouldn’t be separated with space or dash; only a space should be used to separate codes for display.

Assuming the above, the correct regex should look like:

`/([AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]\d{2}|D6W)[0-9AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]{4}/`

[Regex online tester](https://regex101.com/r/bA5qN8/1)

[Ericode guide](http://www.ossiansmyth.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Eircode-Address-File-Product-Guide-Edition-1-Version-8-PUBLISHED.pdf)

Comment: hi kmike, your regex is good for storing eircodes ("Eircode should always be stored as a single string of seven upper case characters") but not great for validating user inputted eircodes, which are likely to contain spaces.

Comment: Also, you need to wrap it is a ^ and $ otherwise it is going to also validate things like 'not an A65TA33 eircode'

Comment: @michaelmcandrew If specification says that it single string, then there shouldn't be possibility to pass eircode with spaces. Front-end should filter or validate input too, same as backend does. I've put `A65TA33` to regex tester linked in my answer and it's marked as valid.

Comment: Given that "Eircode should always be presented in upper case as two parts separated by a space", that's how people will type it in. I'm looking for a regex that will treat that user input as valid. I suspect lots of others will do too.

Comment: To clarify my second comment, without the ^ and $, your regex also marks XA65TA33X as valid, but it not a valid Eircode.

Comment: Just to weigh in on this: I appreciate that a bit of preformatting can be done to strip spaces or change character case, but far more often than not, people _do_ add a space between the routing key and the unique identifier. Eircodes are often presented this way in print and online—notably, even the Eircode lookup site itself always includes this space. Adding `\s*` after the routing key might make this regex more robust for validation.

Comment: Eircode's official spec linked in the question recommends that a space be used—"Our  recommendation  for  displaying an  Eircode  on  screens  or  printed  correspondence  is  to  use  the  three  plus  four  format –  i.e. Routing Key,  space,  Unique Identifier".

Answer (score 4):

Updated this answer avoiding char `B`. You can try this:

```
/^[AC-Y]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9W]{1}[ \-]?[0-9AC-Y]{4}$/
```

---

Description:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[AC-Y]{1} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
A the literal character A (case sensitive)
C-Y a single character in the range between C and Y (case sensitive)
[0-9]{1} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
[0-9W]{1} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: {1} Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
W the literal character W (case sensitive)
[ \-]? match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  the literal character  
\- matches the character - literally
[0-9AC-Y]{4} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: {4} Exactly 4 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
A the literal character A (case sensitive)
C-Y a single character in the range between C and Y (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly what OPs regex do. Note that yours will accept codes with B in the beginning, for example.

Comment: No problem, but it's not only `B` that's not present in Eircode. Also your regex (even after edit) will accept `B`s as your range is *from* `B` *to* `Y` inclusive.

Comment: Ohhhhhh God completely missed. Updated answer thanks again. @Asunez

Comment: Yeah it's not just the letter B that should be excluded though. Check out page 11/12 of this for details - https://www.eircode.ie/docs/default-source/Common/prepareyourbusinessforeircode-edition3published.pdf?sfvrsn=2

Answer (score 3):

Starting from hywak answer and following the other comments suggestions, this is my php regex:

```
/^([AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]\d{2}|D6W)\s[0-9AC-FHKNPRTV-Y]{4}$/
```

I added ^ and $ to define the starting and ending of the string.
Added \s to consider the space and accept the format XXX XXXX.

Reference regarding format letter/numbers and letters to avoid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes

[Regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/bA5qN8/30)

Here the explanation of the last codes that do pass the test:

- D14 N2Fz -> Last letter lowercase
- a65 f4e2 -> All charcters are
  lowercase
- D6W FNTO -> Letter O is not allowed