# Republic of Ireland postcode regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate postcodes (called eircodes) for the Republic of Ireland.

For the UK I used the regex `/^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$/`. I don’t know whether this also applies to Republic of Ireland or whether it have its own specific regex.

Comment: i don't need to use any of extra libraries for this, i am trying to find zipcode and use it

Comment: you can just see regex rule they use, and use it in your project... ;)

Comment: I asked similar a while back and got some good answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391412/validation-for-irish-eircode